# Combine multiple lines dynamically in unix

Tags: unix, shell

I have below scenario:

Iteration 1 -

```
Ddd
Bbb
Ccc
Ddd
Eee
Fff
Ddd
```

Iteration 2 -

```
Ddd
Bbb
Ddd
```

I want to combine the data as below -

Iteration 1 output -

```
Ddd Bbb Ccc
Ddd Eee Fff
Ddd
```

Iteration 2 output -

```
Ddd bbb
Ddd
```

I want to use awk NR to create dynamic chunks to combine data i.e NR%3 in Iteration 1 Output and NR%2 in Iteration 2 Output.

I tried using variable to assign the values dynamically i.e NR%$cnt but it resulted in error.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My method requires no assumption on how frequently `Ddd` occurs; it can occur irregularly. The method should work, unless there is a null character somewhere in your input or the input doesn't end with a newline (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692)), or your tools are limited (e.g. `sed -z` is not specified by POSIX).

```
sed '1! s/^Ddd$/\x00Ddd/' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -z 's/ $/\n/' | tr -d '\0'
```

The procedure:

1. `sed` detects lines that are `Ddd` and precedes each one with a null character, unless the line is the first one. These null characters now separate our lines-to-be.
2. `tr` replaces every newline character with a space character. This builds our lines-to-be: former lines are now separated with spaces.
3. Each but the last line-to-be contains an extra space at its end from the newline originally just before `Ddd`; the last line-to-be contains an extra space from the final newline required by POSIX. `sed -z` reads null terminated strings (lines-to-be) and replaces those trailing space characters with normal newlines. At this moment lines-to-be become regular lines.
4. `tr -d` removes null characters.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use this (it's from GNU coreutils):

```
pr --columns=3 --across --separator=' ' --omit-pagination    # pr -3 -a -s' ' -T
```

It'll read from *stdin* or from a file. Giving it your first column of data the output is as follows:

```
Ddd Bbb Ccc
Ddd Eee Fff
Ddd
```

Change `--columns=3` to `--columns=2` for the second file:

```
Ddd bbb
Ddd
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am actually looking for unix specific commands that can be used in scripts

Comment: Why don't you think this is a Unix command that can be used in a script?

Answer (score 1):

Here's is an option (it's from GNU findutils):

```
xargs --no-run-if-empty --max-args=3    # xargs -r -n3
```

It'll read from *stdin* or from a file. Giving it your first column of data the output is as follows:

```
Ddd Bbb Ccc
Ddd Eee Fff
Ddd
```

Change `--max-args=3` to `--max-args=2` for the second file:

```
Ddd bbb
Ddd
```

---

Here's another option, this time based around `awk`. Change `NR % 3` to `NR % 2` for the second file.

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $0 } { if (NR % 3) { printf " " } else { printf "\n" } }'
```